# How do I continue Excel 2003 worksheet code on the next line?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to continue code to the next line.  I have tried the (space)_ method and get compile errors, expecting seperator or expecting line # etc.... Have also tried & on next line.  My code looks something like this.

```
    Set rangeLimit = Range (A1:A9,B1:B9 on through M9:M37")
```

I need to move to the next line and continue this range all the way through Y9:Y37

I have looked on several help sites and all I have seen point to the things I have already tried.  I am sure I am missing something simple.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set rangeLimit = Range("A1:A9,B1:B9," & _
                "M9:M37")
```

Comment: such concatenation is possible to gather many ranges but I do not quite see the pattern you want to achieve

Comment: I think Kodak wishes to point out that & _ is used to continue text on the next line with concatenation, as opposed to a simple underscore to continue a line that does not need text to be concatenated.

Comment: when we talk about using Range() method with single string parameter then such concatenation is the only way to split it between lines, isn't it? generally it is not clear what range author tries to select

Comment: Thank you!!!  The & _ worked great.  I had not seen that on any of the pages I was able to find.  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

space underscore works for me

```
Set rangeLimit = Range("A1:A9,B1:B9", _
                "M9:M37")
```